# Dynamic Body Color using CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ckeditor

I have a situation on CKEditor that I would like to resolve. I use a jQuery color picker to add background color to a DIV tag. Then I allow the user to edit the Div tag contents using CKEditor. However, I noticed that there isn't a simple way to take the div tag's background color and then make that as the background color of the CKEditor when the editor loads up.

I have read up on bodyClass and bodyId and do not think that these solve my problem. I do not have a class element but an inline style declaration like

```
<div class="tp-header" style="background-color:#CCCCCC;">content</div>
```

I invoke the CKEditor as follows:

```
var editorId = 'editor1';
var instance = CKEDITOR.instances[editorId];
var color = $('.' + headerElementClass).css('background-color');
if (instance) { CKEDITOR.remove(instance); }
$('#' + editorId).ckeditor({ toolbar: 'BasicHtml', height: '100px', width: '500px', fullPage: false, bodyClass : 'background-color:' + color });
$('#' + editorId).val($('.' + headerElementClass).html());
```

Notice the failed usage of **bodyClass**. Is there any way to do this? I have scourged around the site for answers but couldn't find one. I hope someone here has the answer.

Comment: I have requirements same like you. I want to change the background of ckeditor with color picker. For that I tried to add base div to the all content but I obeserved that while editing or deleting the template contents my base div also get affects and get deleted sometimes or it's postion get changed.
And In my case i am providing feature to add/update template.
Can you please help me into this ?

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking about this and I came up with a much simpler solution.
I'm not using the CKEditor jQuery adapter, so you may need to modify it to fit your situation.

I did test it using the standard JavaScript integration approach.

**Quick Overview:**
Set the variables.
Create the editor instance.

Insert this "addCss" function call:

```
CKEDITOR.instances[editorId].addCss( 'body { background-color: '+color+'; }' );
```

---

That's all there is to it. Here's a sample based on your code:

```
// I added the "id" attribute:
<div id="editor1" class="tp-header" style="background-color:#CCCCCC;">content</div>

// Declare the variables, I added "headerElementClass".
var headerElementClass = "tp-header";
var color = $('.' + headerElementClass).css('background-color');
var editorId = 'editor1';

// Create the instance.
var instanceOne = CKEDITOR.replace( editorId,
{
  toolbar: 'Basic',
  height: '100px',
  width: '500px',
  fullPage: false,
  customConfig : 'yourCustomConfigFileIfUsed.js'
 });

// Insert the "addCss" function call:
instanceOne.addCss( 'body { background-color: '+color+'; }' );
```

The addCss function call can be moved to your config file if you prefer (place it outside the editorConfig function).

Be Well,
Joe

---

Leaving the more complicated approach, someone might find the concepts useful.

You could use ( bodyClass: 'nameOfClass' ), then assign a value to the background-color property of that class. But that's difficult because you have a dynamic background color.

To assign the background color dynamically you could do something like this:
Starting with your code and continuing the use of jQuery:

```
var editorId = 'editor1';
var instance = CKEDITOR.instances[editorId];
var color = $('.' + headerElementClass).css('background-color');

// Create a unique body id for this instance "editor1" ( bodyIdForeditor1 )
var idForBody = 'bodyIdFor' + editorId;

if (instance) { CKEDITOR.remove(instance); }

// Use bodyId instead of the original bodyClass assignment
$('#' + editorId).ckeditor({ 
  toolbar: 'BasicHtml', 
  height: '100px', 
  width: '500px', 
  fullPage: false, 
  bodyId : idForBody 
});

$('#' + editorId).val($('.' + headerElementClass).html());

// After both the document and editor instance are ready, 
// assign the background color to the body

// Wait for the document ready event
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Wait for the instanceReady event to fire for this (editor1) instance
  CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on( 'instanceReady', 
    function( instanceReadyEventObj )
    {
      var currentEditorInstance = instanceReadyEventObj.editor;
      var iframeDoc=null;

      // Create a function because these steps will be repeated
      function setIframeBackground()
      {
        // The CKEditor content iframe doesn't have a Name, Id or Class
        // So, we'll assign an ID to the iframe 
        // it's inside a table data cell that does have an Id.
        // The Id of the data cell is "cke_contents_editor1" 
        // Note that the instance name is the last part of the Id
        // I'll follow this convention and use an Id of "cke_contents_iframe_editor1" 

        $("#cke_contents_editor1 iframe").attr("id", "cke_contents_iframe_editor1");

        // Now use the iframe Id to get the iframe document object
        // We'll need this to set the context and access items inside the iframe

        $('#cke_iframe_editor1').each( 
          function(){ iframeDoc=this.contentWindow.document;}
        );

        // Finally we can access the iframe body and set the background color.
        // We set the Id of the body when we created the instance (bodyId : idForBody).
        // We use the iframe document object (iframeDoc) to set the context.
        // We use the "color" variable created earlier

        $('#' + idForBody, iframeDoc).css("background-color", color);
      }

      // Call the function to set the color when the editor instance first loads
      setIframeBackground();

      // When the user switches to "source" view mode, the iframe is destroyed
      // So we need to set the color again when they switch back to "wysiwyg" mode

      // Watch for the "mode" event and check if we're in "wysiwyg" mode
      currentEditorInstance.on( 'mode', function()
      {
        if(currentEditorInstance.mode == 'wysiwyg')
          setIframeBackground();
      });
    }
  );
});
```

Be Well,
Joe

Comment: With the jQuery adapter you can do it this way :

`$('#my-ck-id').ckeditorGet().addCss('body { background-color:'+color+'; }')`

Comment: @MaxiWheat `addCss` doesn't seem to work anymore in version 4.  See [this forum post](http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/addCss-Method-on-editor-object-in-4.0).  Working on an alternative now.

Answer (score 1):

codewaggle's answer is a good one, but if you want to set inline styles on the editor's `<body>` element, you can do that too, using:

```
editor.document.getBody().setStyle()
```

or

```
editor.document.getBody().setStyles()
```

However, you'll need to redo this every time after calling editor.setData() and after the user switches back to wysiwyg mode (from source mode), because these things re-create the editor iframe.  To do all that, set your styles using a function, say `setEditorStyle`, **in which you check first that `editor.mode==='wysiwyg'`** (`editor.document` is null otherwise), then add that function as an event listener for the `instanceReady` and `mode` events; and perhaps also the `contentDom` event if you ever call setData() and don't want to call it manually afterwards.

See some other StackOverflow answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17631771/999120) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11400271/999120)