# Apply background-color in ckeditor textarea

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor

I'm having some problems to apply a background-color in the textarea of a ckeditor instance.

When the user clicks on submit without adding any text, it's shown a message telling him to fill all the required fields, and these required fields areas all with the text-fields set with `background-color: #CFC183;`.

As the ckeditor is created with javascript code, I was using it to try to check if there's any text entered in the text area. if there's no character, I apply the changes. 
When I apply in the console this code:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.body.document.getBody().setStyle('background-color', '#CFC183');
```

It applies the background exactly like I want to.
So, I added this javascript code in my javascript file to try to manage it, but doesn't seems to be working. Here's my code:

```
var editorInstance = CKEDITOR.replace('body', { toolbar : 'Full' });
editorInstance.on("instanceReady", function (ev) { 
    var editorCKE = CKEDITOR.instances.body; readyMap[editorCKE] = true;
    editorCKE.setReadOnly(true); 
});
var hasText = CKEDITOR.instances.body.document.getBody().getChild(0).getText();
if (!hasText) { 
    CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function(e) { 
        e.editor.document.getBody().setStyle('background-color', '#CFC183');
    });
}
```

Firebug shows this error message:

> TypeError: CKEDITOR.instances.body.document is undefined

I'm not that good at Javascript, so is there anything wrong with my code?
I already checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397523/changing-the-background-color-for-ckeditor) here, so I believe there's something wrong with my javascript code and I want your help, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you've got an error in this line:

```
var hasText = CKEDITOR.instances.body.document.getBody().getChild(0).getText();
```

This is because you're trying to get document element before it's ready (before `instanceReady` event).

The same error will be thrown here:

```
if (!hasText) { 
    CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function(e) { 
        e.editor.document.getBody().setStyle('background-color', '#CFC183');
    });
}
```

Again - `instanceCreated` is still too early. You have to move all that code to `instanceReady` listener. You'll have something like (I'm not sure if I understand what you're trying to achieve):

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'body', { toolbar: 'Full' } );
editor.on( 'instanceReady', function( evt ) {
    readyMap[ editor.name ] = true;
    editor.setReadOnly( true ); 

    var hasText = editor.document.getBody().getFirst().getText();
    if ( !hasText ) { 
        editor.document.getBody().setStyle( 'background-color', '#CFC183' );
    }
} );
```

As you can see, there is one more issue in your code:

```
readyMap[editorCKE] = true;
```

In JS there are no weak maps (yet, but they will be introduced soon). Only strings can be used as a keys of an object. In your case `toString()` method will be called on `editorCKE`, which returns `[object Object]`. That's why I added `name` property there.

Comment: thanks for the answer. ur right about the problem! I'm just having an issue with IE9, because in the case where "editor.document.getBody().getFirst().getText()" is empty, I have a javascript error. Do you know how can I solve it?

Comment: You can `getText()` directly on body. But this is very unreliable way of checking if editor is empty. You should at least trim that value.